# How do you assert two functions throw the same error without knowing the error?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have an outer function that calls an inner function by passing the arguments along. Is it possible to test that both functions throw the same exception/error without knowing the exact error type?

I'm looking for something like:

```
def test_invalidInput_throwsSameError(self):
    arg = 'invalidarg'
    self.assertRaisesSameError(
        innerFunction(arg),
        outerFunction(arg)
    )
```

Comment: What is the definition of "same"?  Do you mean the same type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using `unittest` (and python2.7 or newer) and that you're not doing something pathological like raising old-style class instances as errors, you can get the exception from the error context if you use [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) as a context manager.

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception) as err_context1:
    innerFunction(arg)

with self.assertRaises(Exception) as err_context2:
    outerFunction(arg)

# Or some other measure of "sameness"
self.assertEqual(
    type(err_context1.exception),
    type(err_context2.exception))
```

Answer (score 1):

First call the first function and capture what exception it raises:

```
try:
    innerfunction(arg)
except Exception as e:
    pass
else:
    e = None
```

Then assert that the other function raises the same exception:

```
 self.assertRaises(e, outerfunction, arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want; just add it as another method of your TestCase class:

```
def assertRaisesSameError(self, *funcs, bases=(Exception,)):
    exceptions = []

    for func in funcs:
        with self.assertRaises(base) as error_context:
            func()
            exceptions.append(error_context.exception)

    for exc in exceptions:
        self.assertEqual(type(exc), type(exc[-1]))
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. For simplicity this only takes functions with no arguments, so if your function does have arguments, you'll have to make a wrapper (even just with a lambda). It would not be hard at all to expand this to allow for passing in the *args and **kwargs.

Let me know of any changes anyone thinks should be made.